# Smooth scrolling for a UITableView with frequent datasource update

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` for which I update the model after every 2 seconds.
So when doing `reloadData()` on the tableView, the scrolling is not smooth.
What can be done to achieve a smooth scrolling in such case.

Here is what I am doing :

```
//This method is called every 2 seconds    
func UpdateModel(getModel: GetModel) {
     let background = DispatchQueue.global()
     background.async {
      //Replace model objects here
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.testTableView.reloadData()
       }
     }
}
```

How do I ensure here that the scrolling is not affected in the tableView
Note: There are no images loaded in the tableView.

Comment: I suppose it is impossible. Try to use UICollectionView, it hasn't freeze on reload.

Comment: `update the model after every 2 seconds` why such action is done ? Please share the case, there must be more convenient workflow for this.

Comment: If your table has more than one section then you can reload section instead of whole table.

Comment: Make sure you are making API call in background to update model in 2 seconds and reload tableview in main thread... If this is you doing then there is no case for what you are facing

Comment: Yes the API call is inside DispatchQueue.global().async {} block